# Asp.Net Core swagger Help Pages for IFormFile in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-2.0

I found the appropriate solution for my problem in the following question [Asp.Net Core swagger Help Pages for IFormFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892604/asp-net-core-swagger-help-pages-for-iformfile)

Unfortunately, this code works only for older 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' package, that aren't compatible with .Net Core 3.1 version.

Could anyone please help me to update this code, so it will run with no errors with .Net Core 3.1 version?

Thank you!

Comment: If you can provide the exact API definition and the error - it will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: This code doesn't compile for the .net core 3.1 environment because a breaking change was made to the 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' package.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in the 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' package of '6.1.1' version that is already compatible with .Net Core 3.1, the code from my question is already implemented out of the box. Therefore, this additional code is not needed at all!